# Ajax responseText doesn't contain all of the output

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

I just started learning basic Ajax. For now I am not using jQuery ajax yet. But I am having a problem which I couldn't resolve even after lots of searrching.

My php file is-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
while($feedItem = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $feedItem['user']." ";
} 
echo "dd";
```

---

And the file I'm calling it from has the JS script-

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)   {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","loader.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

---

Now, if I run the php file alone, it prints---

> user1 user2 user3 dd

But if I run the other file, the alert only contains "dd". It doesn't alert me with user1 user2...

Why doesn't anything inside the loop get included in the responseText?

Comment: Have you looked at the response in the console/net work tab or with a tool like Fiddler/Charles?

Comment: Did you try to assign the $feedItem['user'] to a variable and then echo the complete result of the loop + your "dd"? Possible problem with multiple echo's where only the last one is reported back.

Comment: I suspect there's some difference in how it's connecting to the DB depending on whether you run the script from the CLI or the webserver.

Comment: And maybe use some placeholder output in the loop to see if the loop is executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well for me, I've tested it.
Use the console to see the raw response coming from the server. But it looks a little strange, do you run the php from the web browser or the cli?
Congrats for not using the jquery ajax! Watch the [XMLHTTPRequest Api](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) to see all you can do in a standard way.